# when.js Promise: then() callbacks is never called

Tags: javascript, callback, jasmine, promise, when-js

**I have:** code snippet like this:

```
Utils.calculate(data).then(
  function(data) { alert('success'); },
  function(data) { alert('error'); }
);
```

**Problem:** Neither `'seccess'` nor `'error'` are called.

**Question:** *What I should to check?*

**P.S.** I launch those code snippet with `jasmine`. So its probably that `then` callback have no time to run. So I decided ti set 1 second timeout at the end of my test - no result.

Comment: Maybe `calculate` takes longer than you anticipated? What does it do? Of course it's also possible that it returns a forever-pending promise (bug? feature?).

Comment: @Bergi no, in real app it works about few milliseconds

Comment: @Bergi ok, so how to check that? I mean in console `Utils.calculate(data)` returns me a promise with `_status=undefined`. I don't know whether it's good or bad

Comment: So, what's the difference between your real and test setup? Of course it should create an initially pending promise, you use them because they're asynchronous.

Comment: Are those actual `alert` calls in your test, or some jasmine functions that are *reported* to be never called?

Comment: @Bergi does it matter? I put a breakpoints inside `then()` callback. They are never called

Comment: @Bergi look pls at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24890816/jasmine-test-promises-howto. Maybe the problem is that jasmine ignores setTimeout?

Comment: I don't think it *ignores* it, it just doesn't know of it.